# Flow Monitor Result is not showing in ns3 simulation

Tags: ns-3

Currently i m using ns-3.19 for my simulation 
I have code of PMIPV6. It is running on my friend system perfectly and showing me Flow Monitor output on the terminal. But when i m running on my system code is running perfectly fine but it is not showing me output of Flow Monitor just like it is showing me on my friend's system. Please help me what i have to do to see the output.
Code file is attached.

Note: Both systems are using same version of ns and ubuntu. Even files are also same. [`Output of my friend system`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQuZI.png)

Code i have here it is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LEMfjUXLj4r7W3wLTBsc99PfyAtouEVX/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it in NS-3.20. It may be a compatibility with NS-3 version.
Follow the below link for more information. Thank you.
https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/

Comment: Can you mention the error occurs when you run the code. Otherwise cannot give a solution for your problem. @Zeeshan